# Can you find a value within one cell and return "n/a" if it is in the cell but is the last or only value in the cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to create a formula that does the following things:

- Checks if a value given is present in a range of cells, then:

  - If it is present but is the LAST value in the cell, return n/a
  - If it is present but is the ONLY value in the cell, return n/a
  - If it is present and neither of the two conditions above apply, return TRUE

Example of what the results might look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thy this in `D1`:

`=arrayformula(if(C1:C<>"",if(countif(flatten(split(regexextract(A1:A,"(.*),.*"),", ",1)),C1:C)>=1,true,"n/a"),))`

[image]

and this in `C1` to get a list from items in Col A:

`=arrayformula(query(flatten(if(A1:A<>"",split(A1:A,", ",1),)),"where Col1 is not null order by Col1",0))`